# How to convert & retrieve image (gif, jpg, png) to and from .tex (LaTex) file?

Tags: android, image, decode, encode, tex

I am *new to game programming* in android and I had decoded an android game using dex2jar and apktool. When I open `assets/images` folder I find lots of `.tex` files there. I renamed those files to `.png, .jpg, .gif , .zip (then unzipped)` but not worked. `I also google out a lot` about it but don't getting exact idea **how to convert image file to such format and retrive original image during game !**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably not a LaTeX file. Latex files don't contain images, and are a way of describing a document. (Like Microsoft word except using a text language instead of an editor.)

Unfortunately I don't think there is a standard .tex image format, they could be any of a variety of formats. Looking around I've seen some places say they they're just .dds files. And other places say they're a custom format. So it really depends on the game you got them from.

I'd pull it open with a hex editor and do some investigating because as it stands there's really no way to tell from the outside. Alternatively if it's a popular game and you're just after the sprites to play around with, someone has probably already ripped them.

Comment: It's jetpack joyride game from halfbricks !